SOGo Login Without Full Email Address in Mailcow Setup
I've set up Mailcow with the SOGo client using Docker Compose. Currently, when logging into SOGo, I need to enter the full email address, for example, joe@domain.com.
However, I'd like to change this behavior so that users can just enter their username (joe), and SOGo automatically appends the domain (domain.com).
Does anyone know how to configure SOGo or Mailcow to achieve this? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
